# Why does the 404 page recommend I email the dev team instead of posting on Meta?

Tags: feature-request, error-message, 404-not-found

The 404 page (https://stackoverflow.com/page/not/found) says

```
If you feel something is missing that should be here, contact us team@stackoverflow.com
```

but the team there sent me here. Why?

Suggestion: I would suggest to add the link to https://meta.stackoverflow.com/ on the 404 page, 
and say, "please consider searching on meta and posting your question there if not found. If you still cannot get satisfaction, then send us a mail at team@stackoverflow.com."

Comment: Personally I think it better point to the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/other) as direct emails are now discouraged and replaced by that form.

Comment: Hah. Yeah, we should probably make that a bit less crazy.

Comment: What it really needs is a different message when you try to view a deleted question than when some other "permanent" page goes missing.

Comment: @BradMace It is different. When you look at a deleted question, the page says "This question was removed from Stack Overflow for reasons of moderation.". Here's [an example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1/where-oh-where-did-the-joel-data-go) (open it in incognito mode if you have 10k on Stack Overflow).

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd yes that makes more sense.

Answer (score 7):

> I would suggest to add the link to https://meta.stackoverflow.com/ on the 404 page, and say, "please consider searching on meta and posting your question there if not found.

Well, *normally* that would be *really bad advice*.

In your case, the page you were trying to access isn't *supposed to be* visible to anyone other than the account owner - so the 404 was... correct... sorta (strictly-speaking, it should've been a 403 page).

This led into a discussion regarding the link that took you there, which *is* a topic appropriate for Meta SO.

But in most cases where you're trying to navigate to a page on SO and come up empty, you'll want to search there first.

Comment: Well some indication about meta would be in order, I did not ever use it before or know to look for it.